# React-native custom font to default system font?

Tags: react-native, fonts

I'm using a third party library for react native and it renders the font in a custom font family, but I want it to default to the system font. How can I define that I want to use the system font and override the custom font. I tried `fontFamily: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'San Francisco' : 'Roboto'` but it errors saying that it doesn't know the San Francisco fontFamily. Does react native have a variable I can use?

All the searches I do are for going from the system font to a custom font but I want the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Found the default system font family:
`fontFamily: 'System'`
https://gist.github.com/parshap/cf9cf0388d55a044004e5e78fa317b39#system-font